# Need Fla file of Maps

Tags: flash, file, maps, fla

I need .fla files of maps to develop map apps in flash. Can anyone tell me from where i can download .FLA files of Maps.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this site : http://freeflashmaps.com/

I think here you can download free .fla file of maps for Free !!!

:)

Answer (score 0):

Nice site for free flash maps...
I got my [australia map](http://freeflashmaps.com/flash-map/australia-flash-maps/australia-map.php) fla from this for free.

maximum maps are frre here.